# dyno printer listen for every row event

Tags: javascript, dymo

Hey guys i have a little issue with my script , im not managing to make the printing script to work for every row.

I know that i need to assign id for every row in the table but

The printing its working only for the first row in table
not an expert on java so if someone could help me i will be greatfull.

```js
   (function()
    {
        

        // called when the document completly loaded
        function onload()
        {

      var model_text    = document.getElementById('model_text');
            var defect_text = document.getElementById('defect_text');
            var imei_text = document.getElementById('imei_text');
            var batch_text = document.getElementById('batch_text'); 
      var printButton = document.getElementById('printButton');

            // prints the label
            printButton.onclick = function()
            {
                try
                {
                    // open label
  ';
                    var label = dymo.label.framework.openLabelXml(labelXml);
                
    
            
                    // set label text
                    label.setObjectText("model_text", model_text.value);
                    label.setObjectText("defect_text", defect_text.value);
                    label.setObjectText('imei_text', imei_text.value);        
                    label.setObjectText('batch_text', batch_text.value); 

                    
                    // select printer to print on
                    // for simplicity sake just use the first LabelWriter printer
                    var printers = dymo.label.framework.getPrinters();
                    if (printers.length == 0)
                        throw "No DYMO printers are installed. Install DYMO printers.";

                    var printerName = "";
                    for (var i = 0; i < printers.length; ++i)
                    {
                        var printer = printers[i];
                        if (printer.printerType == "LabelWriterPrinter")
                        {
                            printerName = printer.name;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (printerName == "")
                        throw "No LabelWriter printers found. Install LabelWriter printer";

                    // finally print the label
                    label.print(printerName);
                }
                catch(e)
                {
                    alert(e.message || e);
                }
            }
        };

        // register onload event
        if (window.addEventListener)
            window.addEventListener("load", onload, false);
        else if (window.attachEvent)
            window.attachEvent("onload", onload);
        else
            window.onload = onload;

    } ());
```

```html
    <script src = "dymo.connect.framework.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"> </script>
    <script src = "PrintLabels.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"> </script>

 

        <title>Phone list</title>
    </head>
       
    <body>


    

        <div class="container">
<span id="success_message"></span>
            <div class="card">
            
                <div class="card-header">
            
            
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col col-md-6"> list</div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                    
<table id="empTable" class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Imei</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Engineer</th>
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>Labour</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        
                     <?php  foreach ($results as $rs)   { ;?>  
            <tr>
            <td><input type="" id="id" name="id" value="<?= $rs['id'] ?>"></td>
                <td><input type="hidden" id="imei_text" name="imei_text" value="<?= $rs['imei'] ?>"><?= $rs['imei'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $rs['date'] ?></td>
                <td ><input type="hidden" id="defect_text" name="defect_text" value="<?= $rs['engineer'] ?>"><?= $rs['engineer'] ?></td>
                <td><input type="hidden" id="model_text" name="model_text" value="<?= $rs['model'] ?>"><?= $rs['model'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $rs['job1_n'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $rs['total'] ?></td>
                <td><input type="hidden" id="batch_text" name="batch_text" value="<?= $rs['status'] ?>"><?= $rs['status'] ?></td>
                <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" onclick="pass_data('<?=$rs["id"];?>')" >Pass</button>&nbsp;
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" onclick="fail_data('<?=$rs["id"];?>')">Fail</button>&nbsp;
            <input type="submit" id="printButton" name="printButton" value="Print" />
                </td>
            </tr>
              <?php $result++;
              } 
              
              echo "Count = $result";
        ?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Imei</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Engineer</th>
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>Labour</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you are going to want to do is make sure you are using the latest version of the [dymo connect framework](https://github.com/dymosoftware/dymo-connect-framework).

Then you need to generate a set of labels using an instance of [`LabelSetBulder`](http://labelwriter.com/software/dls/sdk/docs/DYMOLabelFrameworkJavaScriptHelp/symbols/dymo.label.framework.LabelSetBuilder.html).

Instead of calling the `print` method on the label object itself, you would then call the [`printLabel`](http://labelwriter.com/software/dls/sdk/docs/DYMOLabelFrameworkJavaScriptHelp/symbols/dymo.label.framework.html#.printLabel) method passing in the generated label set data.

```
<script src="http://labelwriter.com/software/dls/sdk/js/dymo.connect.framework.js"></script>

<button id="print"> Print </button>

<script>
  let data = [
    { text : 'TEST1' },
    { text : 'TEST2' }
  ];

  function init() {
    // Fetch your xml format label template
    let labelXml = `
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      ...
      <BarcodeObject>
        <Name>Barcode</Name>
        <Text></Text>
      </BarcodeObject>
    `;

    // Build a label object from xml data
    let barcodeLabel = dymo.label.framework.openLabelXml(labelXml);
    
    // Verify label validity
    if (!barcodeLabel.isValidLabel()) {
      throw new Error('invalid label xml');
    }

    // Initialze a label set builder
    let labelSetBuilder = new dymo.label.framework.LabelSetBuilder();

    // Loop over data and add each record to the label set
    data.forEach(row = > {
      let r = labelSetBuilder.addRecord();
      r.setText('Barcode', row.text);)
    });

    // Get label set data as an xml string
    let labelSetXml = labelSetBuilder.toString();

    // Get printer name
    let printers = dymo.label.framework.getLabelWriterPrinters();
    let printerName = printers[0].name;

    // Set print parameters such as print quality, tape cut mode, etc 
    // See http://labelwriter.com/software/dls/sdk/PrintParams.xsd
    let parametersXml = '';

    // Attach dymo print action to button
    let printButton = document.querySelector('button#print');

    printButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
      dymo.label.framework.printLabel(printerName, parametersXml, labelXml, labelSetXml);
    });
  });

  dymo.label.framework.init(init);
</script>
```